# Django-rest-framework: set default renderer not working?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to build a Django-rest-framework REST API that outputs JSON by default, but has XML available too.

I have read the [Renderers chapter of the documentation section on default ordering](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#ordering-of-renderer-classes), and have put this in my settings file:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
        'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer',
    )
}
```

However, this outputs XML by default. Switching the order makes no difference.

I do get JSON if I append `format=json` to the URL, and if I remove the `XMLRenderer` line altogether.

How can I set JSON to be the default?

I'm using v1.7 of Django and v3.1.1 of Django-rest-framework.

UPDATE: As requested here is the code for my views:

```
class CountyViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = County.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CountySerializer
```

And the serializer:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
class CountySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = County
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'name_slug', 'ordering')
```

And then finally from my urls file:

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'county', CountyViewSet)
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Comment: any solution to this problem? I am facing the same one.

Answer (score 2):

my solution: file renderers.py

```
from rest_framework.negotiation import DefaultContentNegotiation

class IgnoreClientContentNegotiation(DefaultContentNegotiation):

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    def select_renderer(self, request, renderers, format_suffix):
        """
        Select the first renderer in the `.renderer_classes` list.
        """
        # Allow URL style format override.  eg. "?format=json
        format_query_param = self.settings.URL_FORMAT_OVERRIDE
        format = format_suffix or request.query_params.get(format_query_param)
        request.query_params.get(format_query_param), format))

        if format is None:
            return (renderers[0], renderers[0].media_type)
        else:
            return DefaultContentNegotiation.select_renderer(self, request, renderers, format_suffix)
```

Now just need add to settings.py in

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = { 
 (...)
'DEFAULT_CONTENT_NEGOTIATION_CLASS': 'myapp.renderers.IgnoreClientContentNegotiation',
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post your code for the actual views?

Have you defined `renderer_classes` in your views? as this would override the default settings.

```
class YourView(APIView):
    renderer_classes = (XMLRenderer, JSONRenderer, )
```

Comment: Thanks for this. I've updated the question. No, I haven't defined `renderer_classes` in my views.

Comment: If I try doing setting `renderer_classes` as above on an individual view, then XML is still the default, no matter which order I put the classes in. Perhaps this is because the XML renderer is actually a third party module (`djangorestframework_xml`) and it doesn't want to play nicely with the defaults?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the issue you are hitting, especially if you are testing with a browser, is that XML comes before JSON in the `Accepts` header. Because of this, Django REST framework is rendering XML because you specifically requested it, even though its not what you are expecting.

By giving DRF a list of default renderers, you are telling it "use these if I don't tell you to use other ones in my view". DRF will then compare the media types of these to the ones in your `Accepts` header to determine the best renderer to use in the response. The order doesn't matter unless you don't include a specific media type in your `Accepts` header, at which point it should default to the first one in the list.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that I can't force my users (who could be using any browser) to set their `Accepts` header in a certain way. So is it basically impossible to return JSON by default, but also serve XML, using DRF?

Comment: It is _not possible_ to force DRF to _not return_ XML by default when `application/xml` is in the `Accepts` header, _without_ forcing XML to be returned under a different media type. This will then adversely affect any XML clients who actually need to use your API, which is not a good idea.

Comment: It would be much preferable if DRF respected the order specified in my settings, rather than the order specified in the client's Accepts header. The client can always specifically request XML using `format=xml` if they need it.

Comment: take a close look around https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/negotiation.py#L58 It seems me, rest_framework give precedence to browser request ACCEPT_HEADER over the order in render_classes.

Answer (score 0):

Sérgio's answer is correct.

Just to add some more details for anyone in the future that comes across this.

1. Add djangorestframework-xml to pipfile
2. Update

```
RENDERER_CLASSES = (
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework_xml.renderers.XMLRenderer',
)
```

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
   ...
    'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': RENDERER_CLASSES,
}
```

3. add rest_framework_xml to INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework_xml',
]
```

4. Follow Sérgio's advice about creating 'renderers.py'